# Why do colours display differently in texture and solid view? (3D scan)

Tags: texture-painting, 3d-printing

I did a scan of a face which I want to print. It's 4 scans merged together. When I set my interaction mode to texture paint, and my view mode as texture, I see this...[image: texture_view]

However, When I change my view mode to solid, Fiona of shrek appears like this....
[image: hulk]
Not a huge problem. The main problem is, when I want to 3D print in colour, it wants to print the green coloured 1. Why is it green?

I am adding these images to the question due to an answer that was given...
Below is object mode texture view
[image: object,texture]

Below is Texture paint mode, texture view....????[image: paint,texture]
Below is Texture paint mode, solid view.... [image]
Below is when I zoom in on the grey 'Patch'[image: zoomed] 
I imagine it's the grey scratches giving it the discoloured look. I have no idea how or why.

Comment: Could you explain your material set up? Are you using a shadeless material for this texture? I asked about lighting because Blender Render has to have a light in scene for texture paint unless using shadeless. Solid view is a not a good way to preview the texture, but Material View might be better - or even check with Render view for a few seconds.

Answer (score 1):

The bottom picture is possibly what the texture actually looks like, and the texture in the top is affected by the lights in the scene if it is not set to Shadeless in the material. Might want to look at the corresponding texture in the UV Image Editor and check for the green there.

Comment: There is no lighting in the scene. I have added more images from the UV Image editor to the question. Maybe you could give your thoughts on that?

Answer (score 0):

With the material selected: Go to Shader Editor -> Press "N" to toggle the side bar -> click on "Viewport Display" -> change Metallic value to 0.